# PHP preg_replace() pattern

Tags: php, replace

I have about 500 lines stored in a text file.
Each line look like `Filename_662344.xlsx , 324`.

I would like to count numbers at the end of each line (324 in this case).

My idea is to delete part of lines using `preg_replace()` function.
I tried `preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $line);` , but the result was `662344324`

**How should the pattern look like if I want to delete the filename (including numbers);**

Thanks!

Comment: Just use `$parts = explode(',', $line)` and then use `$part[1]` ... no need to fiddle with regex here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d+$` will match the numbers at the end of a string

See [Here](https://regex101.com/r/vG7dZ1/1) for an example of it.

If you are trying to remove everything except the numbers, you can just use `(^.*, )`. This starts at the beginning of the line and select everything up to the comma. See [Here](https://regex101.com/r/lJ9pU5/2) for an example

Comment: Updated my answer if he wants to select everything except the number

Answer (score 2):

Can try this regex.

```
$line = 'Filename_662344.xlsx , 324';
$line = preg_replace("/^(.*?), /", '', $line);
echo $line;
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qG9vH4/1)